# Open multiple workbooks and SUM COUNTIFS

Tags: vba, excel

I’m trying to open multiple workbooks, SUM values of all the COUNTIFS within multiple books/sheets, and divide that sum by an existing value in a master workbook (constantly open), and send that final value to a destination cell in the master workbook.

```
Sub TotalCountIfs()

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Book1.xls"
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Book2.xls"
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Book3.xls"

    Workbooks.Master.Sheet1.Range(“B2″).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.
    SUM
    (Workbooks.Book1.Sheet1.Countif(Range(“A2:A8″), “>”50,
    Workbooks.Book2.Sheet1.Countif(Range(“A2:A8″), “>”50,
    Workbooks.Book3.Sheet1.Countif(Range(“A2:A8″), “>”50)
    /Workbooks.Master.Sheet1.Range(“A2”).Value

    Workbooks("Book1.xls").Close
    Workbooks("Book2.xls").Close
    Workbooks("Book3.xls").Close

End Sub
```

Apologize for the sloppy code. Just trying to convey desired logic. I’m no expert, but I assume a function or loop would save me some trouble since the actual task involves opening 10+ workbooks each with 25+ column ranges.

Comment: Be careful with those 'smart quotes' They are invalid in a code editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way.

```
Sub TotalCountIfs()

    Dim wbm As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook

    Set wbm = ThisWorkbook  '<~~ might need to clarify this
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book2.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book3.xls", ReadOnly:=True)

    wbm.worksheets(1).Range("B2").Value = _
       (application.countif(wb1.worksheets(1).Range("A2:A8"), ">50") + _
        application.countif(wb2.worksheets(1).Range("A2:A8"), ">50") + _
        application.countif(wb3.worksheets(1).Range("A2:A8"), ">50")) / _
        wbm.worksheets(1).Range("A2").Value

    wb1.Close savechanges:=False
    wb2.Close savechanges:=False
    wb3.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

That makes an assumption that wbm.worksheets(1).Range(“A2”).Value is not zero or a #DIV/0! error will result.

Be careful with those 'smart quotes' They are invalid in a code editor.

Comment: Smooth sailing with your fixes bud. Greatly appreciated. Just noticed the smart quote thing :)